# ¿Es ñube una forma antigua de nube?

Tags: modismos

Al sur de la Ciudad de Mexico he escuchado las palabras `ñube` y `ñudo` en lugar de `nube` y `nudo`. Debido a otros modismos escuchados de la misma persona, tiendo a pensar que  las palabras citadas son arcaicas en lugar de ser simples distorsiones. Sin embargo no tengo evidencia concreta.

Comment: Ya que mencionas que se trata de una misma persona, ¿es de origen asturiano o de ancestros asturianos?

Comment: No, local... Pero que buena pista. ¿Puedes expander a una respuest completa?

Comment: Aunque no estaba muy convencido de hacerlo (hay una parte especulativa y eso no me gusta mucho en mis respuestas), finalmente he dado una respuesta.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

La palabra [`ñudo`](http://dle.rae.es/%C3%B1udo) aparece registrada en el DRAE (el enlace anterior lleva a la entrada correspondiente):

> ñudo.
>
> (De nudo, con la ñ de añudar).
>
> 1. m. p. us. nudo.

Así que es una variante de "nudo" pero, como deja ver la marca **m. p. us.**, se trata de un nombre masculino poco usado.

Por otro lado, "ñube" es utilizado en algunas regiones de Asturias por "nube"; trascribo lo que menciona el [`Diccionario General de la Lengua Asturiana (DGLA)`](http://mas.lne.es/diccionario/):

> nube, la.
>
> 1. Nube [Lln. Rs. Pa. Cp. Ca (LBlanco). Ay. Ri. Tb. Sm. JH]. 2. Tormenta [Lln. Rs. Os. Cb. Ac. Llg. Sb. Ca. Ay. Tb. Sm. Pr. VCid]:
>      Vieno la nube ya hubo que s’abilugar [Tb]. Chaparrón [Tb. Sm. Gr].
>      Chaparrón de verano [Ay. Ar]. 3. Mancha en un ojo [Ac. VCid]. 4.
>      Persona de mal humor [Pr].
>
> Frases hechas y locuciones: Andar pelles ñubes ell mar ‘andar por las
>   nubes el mar’ [JH]. //Cayer la nube ‘producirse una tormenta’ [Llg].
>   //La yerba la nube ‘planta semejante al trébol, de hoja muy pequeña y
>   con una manchita blanca en cada una, que se usa para curar las nubes
>   de los ojos’ [Cv]. //Nubes de los güechos ‘nubes de los ojos’ [Sm].
>   //Nube de pedriscu ‘tormenta de truenos y granizo’ [Lln]. //Nube seca
>   ‘tormenta de truenos y rayos pero no de lluvia y pedrisco’ [Lln].
>   //Peles nubes ‘muy caro’ [Sr]. //Tar de nube ‘estar de tormenta’ [Pa
>   (ñube). Llg. Ll. Sl]. ‘amenazar tormenta’ [Pr]. //Una ñube nun güeyu
>   ‘una catarata’ [Pa].
>
> Documentación literaria: Cuando una ñuve tanta piedra allancia [DyE
>   14]. De pardes ñuves velada [El Niño Enfermo 234]. Ansi ñuve de veranu
>   / de goterines preñada [El Niño Enfermo 236]. Tente firme y fala reciu
>   / que ya descargó la ñube [El Camberu 27].
>
> ñube.
>
> v. nube.

Así pues, *ñudo*, aunque es un vocablo poco usado (de hecho, primera vez que lo escucho o leo) es un término castizo aceptado.

En cuanto a *ñube* (también, primera vez que lo escucho o leo), podría tratarse de una deformación dialectal propia de la región, ¿tal vez producto de influencia de inmigrantes asturianos? Por supuesto, esto último es tan solo una conjetura.

Comment: Entiendo la reserva a responder con especulaciones, pero me parece una referencia contundente. Gracias.

Comment: ¡Ah! y un +1 por "ñudo. (De nudo, con la ñ de añudar)".

Comment: _Al que nace barrigón / es al ñudo que lo fajen_